# iOS ARKit: Large size object always appears to move with the change in the position of the device camera

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I am creating an iOS ARKit app where I wanted to place a large object in Augmented Reality.

When I am trying to place the object at a particular position it always appears to be moving with the change in camera position and I am not able to view the object from all angles by changing the camera position.

But if I reduce it's scale value to 0.001 (Reducing the size of the object), I am able to view the object from all angles and the position of the placed object also does not change to that extent.

**Bounding Box of the Object:-**

Width = 3.66

Height = 1.83

Depth = 2.438

[image]

**Model/Object Url:-**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uDDlrTIu5iSRJ0cgp70WFo7Dz0hCUz9D

**Source Code:-**

```
import UIKit
import ARKit
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    private let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    private var node: SCNNode!

    //MARK: - Life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.sceneView.showsStatistics = false
        self.sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints]
        self.sceneView.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = false
        self.sceneView.delegate = self
        self.addTapGesture()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

       configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
       self.sceneView.session.run(configuration)

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.sceneView.session.pause()
    }

    //MARK: - Methods

    func addObject(hitTestResult: ARHitTestResult) {

        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Cube.obj")!
        let modelNode = scene.rootNode.childNodes.first
        modelNode?.position = SCNVector3(hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x,
                                         hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y,
                                         hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
        let scale = 1
        modelNode?.scale = SCNVector3(scale, scale, scale)
        self.node = modelNode
        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(modelNode!)


       let lightNode = SCNNode()
       lightNode.light = SCNLight()
       lightNode.light?.type = .omni
       lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 20)
       self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

       let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
       ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
       ambientLightNode.light?.type = .ambient
       ambientLightNode.light?.color = UIColor.darkGray
       self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)


    }

    private func addTapGesture() {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)))
        self.sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    @objc func didTap(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let tapLocation = gesture.location(in: self.sceneView)
        let results = self.sceneView.hitTest(tapLocation, types: .featurePoint)

        guard let result = results.first else {
            return
        }

        let translation = result.worldTransform.translation

        guard let node = self.node else {
            self.addObject(hitTestResult: result)
            return
        }
        node.position = SCNVector3Make(translation.x, translation.y, translation.z)
        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(self.node)
    }

}

extension float4x4 {
    var translation: SIMD3<Float> {
        let translation = self.columns.3
        return SIMD3<Float>(translation.x, translation.y, translation.z)
    }
}
```

**GIF of the Problem:-**

[image]

**Video URL of the Problem:-**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E4euZ0ArEtj2Ffto1pAOfVZocV08EYKN

**Approaches Tried:-**

1. Tried to place the object at the origin

```
 modelNode?.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
```

2. Tried to place the object at some distance away from the device camera

```
 modelNode?.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -800)
```

3. Tried with the different combinations of worldTransform/localTransform columns

```
modelNode?.position = SCNVector3(hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x, hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y, hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
```

```
modelNode?.position = SCNVector3(hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.2.x, hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.2.y, hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.2.z)
```

```
modelNode?.position = SCNVector3(hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.1.x, hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.1.y, hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.1.z)
```

```
modelNode?.position = SCNVector3(hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.1.x, hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.2.y, hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
```

```
modelNode?.position = SCNVector3(hitTestResult.localTransform.columns.3.x, hitTestResult.localTransform.columns.3.y, hitTestResult.localTransform.columns.3.z)
```

But still of no luck. It still appears to be moving with the device camera and not stuck to a position where it has been placed.

E**xpected Result:-**

1. Object should be of actual size (Scale should be of 1.0). Their should be no reduction in the scale value.
2. Once placed at a particular position it should not move with the movement of the device camera.
3. Object can be seen from all angles with the movement of the device camera without any change in object position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the root cause of the issue. The issue was related to the Model which I was using for AR. When, I replaced the model with the one provided in this link:- https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/quick-look/. I was not facing any issues. So, if anyone face such type of issues in future I would recommend to use any of the model provided by Apple to check if the issue persists with it or not.

Comment: I work on an app that places a house in AR and facing the same issues. All the objects that are in your link are quite small compared to a house. I think that AR is not capable to render large objects that are away more than a few meters correctly! The objects are placed well but start to turn and get an offset ... Please let me know if you have any hints to get AR work on really large objects!

Comment: @Hecot I have tried with large models as well and I didn't face any issues. Can you please try to replace your "house" model with any of the 3D model available in this link (https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/quick-look/) and increase it's scale value to a large number. I have tried by increasing the model size to more than 50 meters and still it worked. May I know the dimensions of your house?

Comment: If still it doesn't work. Is it possible to share the model with me by any means. I will try to figure it out at my end.

Comment: It's 5 floors and 55 x 45 meters! I think ARKit is optimized for distances from 1 - 5 meters, when it comes to much bigger scales the changes of the environment can not be matched. But Yes - would be great if you have a look! Please find the file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z4kcxjjr00saova/5floor_house.scn?dl=0

Comment: @Hecot There is some issue with your model. I tried with one of the apple's model and it is working well. Please find the video link here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3e0006qqphoyoxk/Apple%20Model%20Without%20scaling.mp4?dl=0.

Comment: Your video is very impressive! As I could see, you scan the whole place before placing the object ... I scanned only a few meters. You said there is something wrong with my object - can you be a bit more specific? THANKS!!!

Comment: When I imported your model on AR Viewer app, it was showing me warnings. App Link:- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ar-viewer-augmented-reality/id1253207471. Even, you can also verify this at your end. Error Image Link:- https://www.dropbox.com/s/mykvqr4sb7axgf2/IMG_0190.PNG?dl=0. I would suggest to take help from a professional 3D artist to create your model. Sorry, I cannot do much as I am not a 3D artist.

Comment: The error is about the pivot point that is not in center - I choose this for easier positioning. Meanwhile I broke down the error to the world origin that starts rotating when I look at the Y-axis from top or bottom up.

Comment: Ok. The error was still showing to me even after setting the world transform to origin in my model. That's the reason I suspected there might be some issues with your model. When I created the model from the professional 3D artist it worked for me.

Comment: The 3D artist was using "Maya" to develop the 3D Models.

Comment: @a.palo , i am facing the same issue ... previously i was working with .scn it was working fine ... i am working with VirtualObject (subclass of SCNReferenceNode which apple used in their demo project) ... but suddently the requirement change and i need to work with usdz ... from then ... i am facing this issue .. object moves with the camera mid way in the air ... even i cant interact with it now (pan,tap,rotate)

Answer (score 3):

Unlike stated in the accepted answer, the issue is probably not about the tracking quality or a bug in the model. It looks like the model is not correctly placed on top of the ground, probably due to a mispositioned pivot point, and some part of the model stays under ground. So when you move the camera, since the part under ground is not occluded by the floor, it looks like it is shifting. Have a look at this picture:

[image]

The pivot points of the models provided by Apple are positioned correctly so that when it is placed on top of a plane on the ground, its parts stay above ground.

If you correctly position the pivot point of the model, it should work correctly, independent of the model type.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue.

Whenever I try to change anything in our Model of **.usdz** type (which is actually an Encrypted and compressed type) we cannot edit or change anything in it. If I edit or change a little position then it behaves same way as highlighted in the question.

To handle this issue, I just moved the old model `.usdz` to trash and and copied the original file (again) to XCode and then it worked.